# How to hide 'lastname' field

Tags: python, xml, odoo

model: partner_firstname.
I am trying to hide a field using a group (without using inheritance, for simplicity)

```
lastname = fields.Char(
        "Last name",
        index=True,
        groups='cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts',
    )
```

I get: Uncaught Error: Unknown field lastname in domain.
I tried to comment something like this:

```
<field name="firstname" attrs=
                            "{'required': [('lastname', '=', False),
                            ('is_company', '=', False),
                            ('type', '=', 'contact')]}"/>
```

But it did not help.
For example, for this field everything works:

```
middlename = fields.Char(
        "Middle name",
        index=True,
        groups='cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts',
    )
```

I also tried to write:

```
...
<field name="lastname" attrs=
                                "{'required': [('firstname', '=', False),
                                ('is_company', '=', False),
                                ('type', '=', 'contact')]}" groups='cmz_security_contacts.field_invisible_from_contacts'/>
...
```

and it works for this form (base.view_partner_form)

Comment: Can you post your code more details?

Answer (score 0):

Whichever field you use in domain or attrs that fields needs to be defined in xml file of your view.

So your probelm solved by defining that `lastname` field in xml file above the first name and make it invisible like this.

```
<field name="lastname" invisible="1"/>
```